# composition and inheritance - abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Lets suppose i have a super class `WorkStation`, and two subclass `StationNormal`, `StationAdvanced`.  I have another class `Robot`, which has a `WorkStation` pointer that will start as a `StationAdvanced` but it can change, but my class `WorkStation` is a abstract class. I think class `Robot` should be something like this:

```
class Robot{
 private: 
       WorkStation * actualStation;
...
}
```

My question is how Robot class constructor should be defined if my class `WorkStation` is abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should be sufficient:

```
class Robot{
 private: 
        WorkStation * actualStation;
 public:
        Robot();
        Robot(WorkStation * w);
}

Robot::Robot() // constructor that takes no arguments
{
    actualStation = new StationAdvanced();
}

Robot::Robot(WorkStation * w) // constructor that takes specific WorkStation
{
    actualStation = w;
}
```

You can invoke it with:

```
Robot rob1(),
      rob2(new StationAdvanced()),
      rob3(new StationNormal());
```

Comment: My get and set are the following:
void Robot::setActualStation(WorkStation* w){
 actualStation  = w;
}
Posto* Robot::getActualStation() const{
 return actualStation;
}

if i need to change the workstation of rob2, how should i procced? thanks for your answer, it was very helpfully

Comment: Using your get and set would work.  Make sure you get the workstation and delete it before assigning a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let `StationNormal` and `StationAdvanced` inherit `WorkStation`
An example would be:

```
class StationNormal:public WorkStation
{
  ....
}

public Robot(WorkStation* workStation)
{
  actualStation = workStation;
}
```

In main method for example:

`new Robot(new StationNormal()) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your constructor you would instantiate the actual WorkStation and tell the pointer (`WorkStation * actualStation`) to point to it. Put this in your constructor:

```
this->actualStation = new StationAdvanced(...)
```